# Get context in Polly.Policy `onHalfOpen`

Tags: c#, polly, circuit-breaker

It does not seem any of the overloads of `AdvancedCircuitBreakerAsync` pass the `Context` to `onHalfOpen` action, so I am wondering if there is any workaround.

```cs
var cB = Policy
    .Handle<Exception>()
    .AdvancedCircuitBreakerAsync(
        getFailureThreshold(),
        getSamplingDuration(),
        getMinimumThroughput(),
        getDurationOfBreak(),
        onBreak: (exception, timeSpan, context) =>
        {
            var logger = context.GetLogger();
            logger.LogWarning("In Break");
        },
        onReset: (context) =>
        {
            var logger = context.GetLogger();
            Logger.LogWarning("In Reset");
        },
        onHalfOpen: () =>
        {
            // How do I get the context here?
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

The sad truth is that you can't. If you look at the [related source code](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/blob/ab957f2b70529234854333858d77a74e89eb9809/src/Polly/CircuitBreaker/AsyncCircuitBreakerSyntax.cs) then you can see that all `CircuitBreakerAsync` overloads, which can accept a `onHalfOpen` delegate, are defined in a way that `onHalfOpen` is an `Action`:

```
public static AsyncCircuitBreakerPolicy CircuitBreakerAsync(this PolicyBuilder policyBuilder, int exceptionsAllowedBeforeBreaking, TimeSpan durationOfBreak, Action<Exception, TimeSpan> onBreak, Action onReset, Action onHalfOpen)

public static AsyncCircuitBreakerPolicy CircuitBreakerAsync(this PolicyBuilder policyBuilder, int exceptionsAllowedBeforeBreaking, TimeSpan durationOfBreak, Action<Exception, TimeSpan, Context> onBreak, Action<Context> onReset, Action onHalfOpen)

public static AsyncCircuitBreakerPolicy CircuitBreakerAsync(this PolicyBuilder policyBuilder, int exceptionsAllowedBeforeBreaking, TimeSpan durationOfBreak, Action<Exception, CircuitState, TimeSpan, Context> onBreak, Action<Context> onReset, Action onHalfOpen)
```

Sadly the same is true for [`AdvancedCircuitBreakerAsync`](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/blob/ab957f2b70529234854333858d77a74e89eb9809/src/Polly/CircuitBreaker/AdvancedCircuitBreakerTResultSyntax.cs) as well

```
public static CircuitBreakerPolicy<TResult> AdvancedCircuitBreaker<TResult>(this PolicyBuilder<TResult> policyBuilder, double failureThreshold, TimeSpan samplingDuration, int minimumThroughput, TimeSpan durationOfBreak, Action<DelegateResult<TResult>, TimeSpan> onBreak, Action onReset, Action onHalfOpen)

public static CircuitBreakerPolicy<TResult> AdvancedCircuitBreaker<TResult>(this PolicyBuilder<TResult> policyBuilder, double failureThreshold, TimeSpan samplingDuration, int minimumThroughput, TimeSpan durationOfBreak, Action<DelegateResult<TResult>, TimeSpan, Context> onBreak, Action<Context> onReset, Action onHalfOpen)

public static CircuitBreakerPolicy<TResult> AdvancedCircuitBreaker<TResult>(this PolicyBuilder<TResult> policyBuilder, double failureThreshold, TimeSpan samplingDuration, int minimumThroughput, TimeSpan durationOfBreak, Action<DelegateResult<TResult>, CircuitState, TimeSpan, Context> onBreak, Action<Context> onReset, Action onHalfOpen)
```

Someone has filed an [issue](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/issues/882) back in 2021 with the same problem. It might make sense to ask for update.

---

Here are some closed issues with the same concern: [1](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/issues/806), [2](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/issues/311), ...